# Java terminal process switch

Tags: java, terminal, java-io

I'm building a library for making command line games as a fun project, and while I have most of the code done, I've hit a roadblock with end-user viewing. What I would like is when the application is jpackaged, the user runs it, and it opens a terminal window. While I have opened a window using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/open -a Terminal");`, I was wondering how I could make it so - using the process returned from `.exec(...)` - that window is the one which is running the application. Example; thats the window where `System.out.println` prints to.
Is this even possible, or should I be doing it a different way.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 methods that I know about.

Method 1 : If you've coded the game and made it a JAR.
You can type this in CMD to print the game in CMD.EXE

`java -jar "LocationOfJar"`

like `java -jar C:/Users/TOP10/Desktop/Game.jar`

or if the command is in the same folder as the jar.. `java -jar Game.jar`

Method 2 : Create an `OutputStream` and connect it to a `JFrame` with a `JTextField`.

Create an `OutputStream` that streams outputs to a Text field in a window that your library should show.

More Info : [how to visualize console java in JFrame/JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776465/how-to-visualize-console-java-in-jframe-jpanel)

Comment: Please share the library with me if that is possible.